# Servlet request.getParameter() returns null

Tags: java, servlets, getparameter

I have read all the questions about this here, but I still do not have any progress. I want to pass the value from the input field to my servlet, but the servlet's request.getParameter returns null, instead of what is inputted. Here is my HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="MyHttpServletDemo" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="input" name="input1" placeholder="    Input coordinates...">
</form>
    <a href="welcome"><button type="button" id="vnes" onclick="Vnes()">Search</button></a>
```

Here is my .xml:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>MyHttpServletDemo</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>MyServletDemo</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>MyHttpServletDemo</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And the Servlet:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

      response.setContentType("text/html");

      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      
      String value = (String) request.getParameter("input1");
      out.println("<h1>" + value + "</h1>");
   }
```

I tried this:

```
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      String value = (String) request.getParameter("input1");
      out.println("<h1>" + value + "</h1>");
   }
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/welcome" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="input" name="input1" placeholder="    Input coordinates...">
 <a href="welcome"><button type="button" id="vnes" onclick="Vnes()">Search</button></a>
</form>
```

And still does not work.

Comment: Your form has `method="post"`, but you've implemented `doGet`. Was that an accident? And how are you submitting that form? With `Enter` on the input text field?

Comment: @ernest_k I tried to change it to doPost, it doesn't work either. I submit it by clicking on the button, it works, but it returns null always.

Comment: Your button is outside the form. So you use some JS magic to do something with the form. So how are you actually sending the form to the backend.

Comment: @M.Deinum I've put the button in the form and tried with
myForm=document.getElementById("myForm"); myForm.submit();
It does not work.

Comment: your form isn't submitted to `/welcome` so it doesn't go anywhere. Also why the javascript just post a form with the button instead of hiding this with javascript. So ditch the javascript, place a simple button inside the form and change the action to `/welcome` and implement `doPost` instead of `doGet`.

Comment: @M.Deinum It won't work. I tried just now.

Comment: Then I suspect you haven't done as explained, please add the modified code.

Comment: @M.Deinum I updated the question.

Comment: Why is your button inside a `<a href>`? It should be just a button. Also it should **not** invoke javascript and type should be `submit` or remove it all together.

Comment: @M.Deinum I saw it as an answer to another question about this, I tried without the <a> tag, also does not work.

Comment: And as mentioned it shouldnt' invoke javascript **and** the type should be `submit`. I mentioned multiple things but you haven't addressed all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked! Here's the solution:
HTML:

```
<form method="get" action="welcome" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="pole" name="pole1" placeholder="    Input coordinates...">
    <button type="submit" id="vnes">Search</button>
</form>
```

.xml file:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>MyHttpServletDemo</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>MyServletDemo</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>MyHttpServletDemo</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Servlet:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      String value = (String) request.getParameter("pole1");
      out.println("<h1>" + value + "</h1>");
}
```

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash It didn't work with method="post" and the action has welcome as a value.

Comment: Programmer2B - I see...I didn't even notice that you had a mistake in `action`. Good luck! Just to avoid such problems, I use annotation rather than `web.xml`.